# getting sensitivity after fitting decision tree with caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to obtain the sensitivity and specificity etc. after fitting a decision tree using carret (or even caret::confusionMatrix). I am using code along those lines:

```
fit <- rpart(
        Bla ~ ...
        ,method="class"
        ,data=OrginalData
)

preds <- predict(fit, SomeData)

caret::sensitivity(factor(preds[,2]), factor(OrginalData$Bla))
str(preds)
```

Unfortunately, I get NA as sensitivity. Str returns:

```
num [1:40, 1:2] 0.926 0.926 0.926 0.926 0.926 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:40] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "NO" "YESR"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are providing a numeric vector of probabilities as predictions while `caret::sensitivity` expects a vector of classes. Here is a working code with Sonar data from mlbench:

```
library(mlbench)
library(rpart)
library(caret)

data(Sonar)
```

split data:

```
inds <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = 0.7, list = FALSE)

train <- Sonar[inds,]
test <- Sonar[-inds,]
```

create model:

```
fit <- rpart(Class ~ .,
             method = "class",
             data = train)

pred <- predict(fit, test)
```

convert probability to prediction:

```
caret::sensitivity(as.factor(ifelse(pred[,2] > 0.5, "R", "M")), test$Class)
#output
[1] 0.6969697
```

Do note that 0.5 as threshold might not be appropriate and it should be tuned according to the desired model behavior. If there is no preference towards a certain type of error, balanced accuracy is a solid metric to tune the probability threshold.

or specify `type = class` when predicting rpart:

```
pred <- predict(fit, test, type = "class")
caret::sensitivity(pred, test$Class)
```